# Incorrect runtime version of the built assembly in .Net Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

The project target framework has been set to .Net 2.0 but after building the project, the dll file that's generated has a run time version of v4.0.30319.

As a result, I am not able to include this assembly back into the 2.0 project. Any ideas how to get the correct run-time version?

Comment: K; how exactly was it generated, built, etc? What was the process here?

Comment: Simply opened the project in VS2010, right-clicked on project and clicked Build... on Windows 7 Home...

Comment: How are you verifying the runtime version? Is that dll referenced anywhere? After changing the Target Framework, did you remember to recompile that project?

Comment: If by recompiling you mean build, then yes.

Comment: When I reference the newly built library in another project, I can see in VS2010, the runtime version is v4.0.30319. It also gives me a warning that the assembly has been built using a newer runtime version.